# Errors in settings.json in Vscode? Incorrect type expected null and end of file expected?

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

I've got some errors in my settings.json file in Vscode and not sure how to go about rectifying them, it's preventing me from doing some stuff like adjusting Python Interpreter path and such. Never really messed with the settings in this way so I'm a bit lost as to how to remedy it, perhaps someone could take a look and point me in the right direction? TIA ! Here is what I have in settings.json:

```
{
    "security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
    "code-runner.runInTerminal": true,
    "explorer.compactFolders": false,
    "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "C:\\Users\\golda\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\python.exe",
    "terminal.integrated.automationProfile.windows": {
}
}

"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": ["-ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass"]
```

The only modification was adding the last line a few days ago in order to have permission to install some things, but it was pretty benign like flask, and everything worked correctly since. However now if I remove the last line there's still errors... The "incorrect type, expected Null" occurs between the open and closed curly braces in lines 6-7. It also shows an end of file expected error :/ Thanks again kinda lost

Comment: you placed the last line not inside the object, move it above the last `}`

Comment: Hmm ok, I've tried this but it still shows the "expected null" error. Then for ""terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": ["-ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass"]" it reads "This is deprecated, the new recommended way to configure your default shell is by creating a terminal profile in `#terminal.integrated.profiles.windows#` and setting its profile name as the default in `#terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows#`. This will currently take priority over the new profiles settings but that will change in the future." which to my understanding should still work but isn't ideal

Comment: start with an empty object as `settings.json` and add line by line to find the offending line for the `expected null`